# Action script - TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript

First am only been doing action script 2weeks and apologise for what appears To be a easy task for most. On timeline I've 2 frames the first frame just has a button to go to the next screen.The second screen has a 2 buttons to allow to go forward or backward 1 frame.

I have 1 class file named main which am using for all the action script 
the program works fine until I add the event listeners for the 2 buttons on the 2 frame then i get the the TypeError:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.\Desktop\weather\Main.as:17]

Debug session terminated.

Line 17 straight after the stop function

```
    package 
     {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {


        public function Main()
        {
            // constructor code
            Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClicked);
            stop();
            back_btn.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backClicked);
            forward_btn.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,forwardClicked);


        }
        function playClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {

            nextFrame();
        }
        function backClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (currentFrame == 1)
            {
                gotoAndStop(totalFrames);
            }
            else
            {
                prevFrame();
            }
        }
        function forwardClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
            {
                gotoAndStop(1);
            }
            else
            {
                nextFrame();
            }
        }



    }

}
/*
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backClicked);
forward_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, forwardClicked);
stop();

function backClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
if(currentFrame == 1)
{
gotoAndStop(totalFrames);
}
else
{
prevFrame();
}
}

function forwardClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{

if(currentFrame == totalFrames)
{
gotoAndStop(1);
}
else
{
nextFrame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
function Main()
{
  if(!stage){
    addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
  }
  else{
    onAddedToStage(null);
  }
}
function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{
  if(hasEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE)){
    removeEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
  }

  Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClicked);
  stop();
  back_btn.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backClicked);
  forward_btn.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,forwardClicked);
}
```